# Extract specific bundle product orders

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how can i extract specific bundle product orders from the following tables. for example, if i wanna extract all orders where product `Wireless Mouse` has been used as bundle products.

**Expecting result 1:**

```
    orders_id     product_name       qty    
       1000      Wireless Mouse      1
       1000      Laptop              1
       1001      Wireless Mouse      3
       1001      PC                  3
       1003      Wireless Mouse      4
       1003      IPAD                4
```

**Second Question:**

if i wanna extract only the products orders which are used with "Wireless Mouse" as bundle how can I do that?

**Expecting result 2:**

```
    orders_id     product_name       qty    
       1000      Laptop              1
       1001      PC                  3     
       1003      IPAD                4
```

**if possible please help me about the following:**

if i wanna extract only the "Laptop" orders which are used with "Wireless Mouse" as bundle how can I do that?

**Expecting result 3:**

```
    orders_id     product_name       qty    
       1000      Laptop              1
```

**Example Data:**

**Table 1: orders**

```
    id   customer_id      order_price  purchase_date
    1000   1                   203     12/6/2011
    1001   2                   304     12/6/2011
    1002   1                   1000    12/6/2011
    1003   1                   233     12/6/2011
    1004   1                   44      12/7/2011
    1005   3                   50      12/7/2011
    1006   4                   67      12/7/2011
    1007   5                   99      12/7/2011
    1008   6                   299     12/7/2011
    1009   7                   199     12/7/2011
```

**Table 2 : customers**

```
    id  email                          name
    1   aa@dealboard.com.au            james
    2   bb@dealboard.com.au            Ryan
    3   cc@live.com.au                 Sili
    4   dd@acgglobal.com               Mame
    5   ee.heinrich@det.nsw.edu.au     Kane
    6   ff@optusnet.com.au             Kratos
    7   ssy@hotmail.com                Kim
```

**table 3: products**

```
    id  name
    1   Laptop
    2   PC
    3   Wireless Mouse
    4   IPAD
    5   iphone
    6   Wireless Keyboard
    7   Printer
    8   Glaxy S3
    9   Scanner
    10  PS3
```

**table 4: product_orders**

```
    id     orders_id product_id qty
        1   1000      1         1
        2   1000      3         1
        3   1001      2         3
        4   1001      3         3
        5   1003      4         4
        6   1003      3         4
        7   1004      5         1
        8   1005      6         1
        9   1007      7         2
        10  1008      8         1
```

Sorry guys, i have asked too much today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **Question No. 1**

As you can see below, the query is nested.

**Subquery 2** gets all the orders_id which has `Wireless Mouse` on it. 
**Subquery 1** counts the number of records for each `Orders_ID` in which `Wireless Mouse` is present. 
**Main Query** joins the subquery from `products_orders` and `products`

```
Main Query
  -- Subquery 1
     --- Subquery 2
```

Query.

```
SELECT   aaa.orders_id, bbb.name, aaa.qty
FROM     products_orders aaa
         INNER JOIN products bbb
             ON bbb.id = aaa.product_id
         INNER JOIN
          (
            SELECT  aa.ORDERS_ID
            FROM    products_orders aa
                    INNER JOIN
                    (
                      SELECT  orders_id
                      FROM    products_orders a
                              INNER JOIN products b
                                ON b.id = a.product_id
                      WHERE   name = 'Wireless Mouse'
                    ) bb ON aa.orders_id = bb.orders_id
            GROUP BY aa.ORDERS_ID
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
          ) ccc ON aaa.orders_id = ccc.orders_id
ORDER BY aaa.orders_ID
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4464/11)

For **Question No 2**

From `Question No 1`, you can just add addition condition on the `WHERE` clause to filter all records without `Wireless Mouse`

```
...
WHERE   bbb.name <> 'Wireless Mouse'
```

Query,

```
SELECT   aaa.orders_id, bbb.name, aaa.qty
FROM     products_orders aaa
         INNER JOIN products bbb
             ON bbb.id = aaa.product_id
         INNER JOIN
          (
            SELECT  aa.ORDERS_ID
            FROM    products_orders aa
                    INNER JOIN
                    (
                      SELECT  orders_id
                      FROM    products_orders a
                              INNER JOIN products b
                                ON b.id = a.product_id
                      WHERE   name = 'Wireless Mouse'
                    ) bb ON aa.orders_id = bb.orders_id
            GROUP BY aa.ORDERS_ID
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
          ) ccc ON aaa.orders_id = ccc.orders_id
WHERE   bbb.name <> 'Wireless Mouse'
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4464/9)

For **Question No 3**

just like *question No 2*, add extra condition

```
...
WHERE   bbb.name <> 'Wireless Mouse' AND
        bbb.name = 'Laptop'
```

Query,

```
SELECT   aaa.orders_id, bbb.name, aaa.qty
FROM     products_orders aaa
         INNER JOIN products bbb
             ON bbb.id = aaa.product_id
         INNER JOIN
          (
            SELECT  aa.ORDERS_ID
            FROM    products_orders aa
                    INNER JOIN
                    (
                      SELECT  orders_id
                      FROM    products_orders a
                              INNER JOIN products b
                                ON b.id = a.product_id
                      WHERE   name = 'Wireless Mouse'
                    ) bb ON aa.orders_id = bb.orders_id
            GROUP BY aa.ORDERS_ID
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
          ) ccc ON aaa.orders_id = ccc.orders_id
WHERE   bbb.name <> 'Wireless Mouse' AND
        bbb.name = 'Laptop'
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4464/10)

Comment: thanks for help. one interesting thing is, i didn't know that <> is "not equal". i have learned a lot today from u. thanks again.